# Why is the output 1? is it because it's true?

Tags: c

The while part confuses me, when it says j++ does it j=2 or 3?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() {
int i=2,j=2;
while(i+1?--i:j++) 
    printf("%d",i);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `while` condition seems to have been written with the intent to confuse. Anyone wiring such code should be should be shot... a book on writing readable code.

Comment: And to address your question, did you debug it? This would be very easy to answer on your own.

Comment: I agree with @Carcigenicate - I've never seen and would never use a ternary in a while.

Comment: @BryanT This is the first time I've ever seen it used like this. I've seen a million ternarys, and this took me longer than I'm willing to admit to figure out.

Comment: @BryanT `while (x ? f() : g())` is reasonable

Comment: @M.M - that I can understand at first glance. Unlike the one in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `while` expression, `i+1?--i:j++`, first checks to see if `i+1` is non-zero.  If so, then it evaluates `--i`, using it as the `while` test.  If not, it evaluates `j++`, using it as the `while` test.

Initially `i` is 2, so `i+1` is 3 which is non-zero.  So it evaluates `--i`, which is 1, and `i` is now 1.  It then executes the body, printing 1.

The second time around, `i` is 1, so `i+1`is 2 which is non-zero.  So it again evaluates `--i`, which is 0, and `i` is now 0.  It then exits the loop, since the value of the `while` expression is 0.

Comment: So j is never really tested (under the initial conditions of i=2 and j=2). And it never gets printed or used.

Answer (score 0):

This is very confusing but easier to understand if you break the ternary expression out of the while.

```
x = i+1?--i:j++;
```

the value of x will determine whether the while continues or not.

then the value of x would be as such:

```
(i = 2, j = 2)
x = i+1?--i:j++ = 3 ? --i : _ // i + 1 == 3 which != 0, so x = --i which is 1, j is ignored
(i = 1, j = 2)
x = i+1?--i:j++ = 2 ? --i : _ // i + 1 == 2 which != 0, so x = --i which is 0, j is ignored
```

at this point while(x) would break out of the loop because x = 0 = false. 
The printf is only called once, with the value of x which at that point is 1